# CMake gazebo package not found when installing from source

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

After installing gazebo 3.0 from source (the installation path being my local home folder) the `pkg_check_modules(GAZEBO gazebo)` command from CMake does not find the `gazebo` package:

```
-- checking for module 'gazebo'
--   package 'gazebo' not found
```

As a workaround I added the absolute path for `GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS` in the `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
 set(GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS /home/<path>/include/gazebo-3.0;/usr/include/sdformat-2.0)
 set(GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS /home/<path>/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
```

Any way to fix this, or is it a bug?

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6328/cmake-gazebo-package-not-found-when-installing-from-source/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2014-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If it is not strictly necessary to use `pkg_check_modules`, you can try with

```
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)
```

That for me works perfectly with gazebo 3.0 installed from source.

---

Originally posted by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) with karma: 200 on 2014-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-06-02**:
thank you kind sir, it worked :)